# Uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need a help to answer the following problem:

Assume that $\left\{a_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $\left\{A_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset \mathbb{C}$ where $\underset{n\to \infty}{lim} \;a_n = \infty.$

Prove that there is an entire function $f$ such that $f(a_n) = A_n$ for all $n ∈\in \mathbb{N}$.

Hint: Let $g$ be entire with simple zeros at $\left\{a_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}.$ Prove that the series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{A_n}{g'(a_n)}\frac{e^{c_n(z-a_n)}}{z-a_n}g(z)
\end{align*}
converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C},$ provided $c_n$ are selected appropriately.

Thanks in advance.